# How to change shortcut keys in Thunderbird 3 for Linux?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, thunderbird

I use Thunderbird on Ubuntu Linux and have just upgraded to Ubuntu 10 / Thunderbird 3. One of my gripes however is that Thunderbird uses a number of shortcut keys that have no secondary key requirements, for example, "Mark as Read" is <kbd>M</kbd>. Not <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>. Just <kbd>M</kbd>. Worse, "Mark as Junk" is <kbd>J</kbd>. Which means I sometimes inadvertently mark messages as Junk.

How can I customize Thunderbird's shortcuts so, for example, "Mark as Junk" is <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [keyconfig extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/functions-for-keyconfig-thunde/).

[image]

Comment: Perfect thanks! For those reading this later the actual link is http://mozilla.dorando.at/keyconfig.xpi